# Find PDF of a function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Find the distribution of $Y = g(X)$ knowing that $$ g(X) =\begin{cases}X & \text{if}&|X|\geq 1 \\0 & \text{if}&|X| < 1 \end{cases}$$

and

a) let $X$ be a Uniform(−1,1) continuous random variable

b) $p_{\small X} = \frac 14\delta_{-1} + \frac 12\delta_2 + \frac 14f_{\small X}$, where $f_{\small X}(x) = \left(\tfrac{x}{\surd(2\pi)}\right)e^{-{x^2}/{2}}$

so in part b) the probability that I will get -1 is $\frac 14$ and $\frac 12$ for 2 and the rest is the function, idk if that makes it more clear, frankly I dont understand it too well myself and the language barrier doesn't seem to help

I would be immensely grateful if someone could write me a step by step solution to this problem as I struggle quite a bit with this topic and seeing an example solution would help me understand it better (or at all lmao, remote learning kinda sucks :/)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: In part a), $X$ only takes values between $-1$ and $1$ so $Y=X$.  In part b) I can't understand what you have written.

Comment: @saulspatz $Y=0$ , because $g((-1..1))=\{0\}$

Comment: @swagotato, you have not provided the support for $f_{\small X}$

Comment: @saulspatz Also, $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $g:(-\infty..\infty)\mapsto(-\infty..1]\cup\{0\}\cup [1..\infty)$ with, in particular, $g((-1..1))=\{0\}$.

---

So for (a): since $X\in(-1..1)$ then $Y$ will be degenerate: ie $Y=0$ a.s..   We use the Dirac delta function: $$p_{\small Y}(y)=\delta_0(y)$$

---

So for (b):

Likewise $Y$ will have a degeneracy at $0$, just as $X$ does at $-1$ and $2$, and the coefficient will be the probability mass at this degeneracy. IE the probability that $\lvert X\rvert<1$

The remaining probability density will only be supported when $y\leq -1$ or $y\geq 1$.  We use the indicator function for this.

$$p_{\small Y}(y)=\tfrac 14\delta_{-1}(y)+\tfrac 12\delta_2(y)+\mathsf P(\lvert X\rvert<1)\,\delta_0(y)+f_{\small X}(y)\mathbf 1_{\lvert y\rvert\geq 1}$$

Now you have been given $f_{\small X}$ so may evaluate this probability.